# Why is Kafka consumer ignoring my "earliest" directive in the auto.offset.reset parameter and thus not reading my topic from the absolute first event?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka topic I want to read from the earliest event.

What I want to do is to get all the data from a topic (from the absolute earliest event in time) until the events at a certain date.

The structure of each event has a field called `dateCliente` which I use as a threshold to filter events. So far, I've managed to complete the read and write. I'm writing to an temporary parquet file which I use as a partition for a Hive table. This is working OK, however, even though I have specified earliest in the `auto.offset.reset` parameter, it's not reading data from the start.

Whenever I run my code I get all the events starting from this date. And every time I execute the code again, it keeps reading from the Kafka event following the last one I read in the previous code execution.

The code I'm using to configure the Kafka Consumer and subscribe to the topics is the following:

```
  // Configurations for kafka consumer
  val conf = ConfigFactory.parseResources("properties.conf")
  val brokersip = conf.getString("enrichment.brokers.value")
  val topics_in = conf.getString("enrichment.topics_in.value")
  //

  // Crea la sesion de Spark
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("yarn")
    .appName("XY")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  import spark.implicits._


  val properties = new Properties
  properties.put("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
  properties.put("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])
  properties.put("bootstrap.servers", brokersip)
  properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
  properties.put("group.id", "XY")

  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](properties)
  consumer.subscribe( util.Collections.singletonList("geoevents") )
```

However, whenever I create a consumer from the command line in order to read the data from the topic, I do get all the events from the previous days.
The command line command I run is:

```
kafka-console-consumer --new-consumer --topic geoevents --from-beginning --bootstrap-server xx.yy.zz.xx
```

Any ideas of why is my code behaving like that and ignoring my `"earliest"` in `auto.offset.reset`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because `auto.offset.reset` is only applied if there are no committed offsets for the group.

See the consumer configs [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs):

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current
>   offset does not exist any more on the server

If you want to restart from the beginning, you can either:

- use a new group name (for example append `System.currentTimeMillis()` to the group anme)
- explicitly move the position of the consumer to the start of the partition using `seekToBeginning()`: http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seekToBeginning-java.util.Collection-

Answer (score 4):

The property `auto.offset.reset` is used only when there is no offset for the given consumer stored in Kafka. When you commit the record Kafka stores the offset of the record in a special topic and in the next run, your consumer will read the topic from the last committed offset. To read from the beginning you should call `consumer.seekToBeginning` or use unique `group.id` property.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to read the topic from the first event for all the partitions then you can reset the offsets

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <host-ip>:<port> --group <group-name> --reset-offsets --execute --to-earliest --topic <topic>
```